# Ionic iOS input field is getting hidden behind keyboard

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-keyboard

I am trying to show ion-input at the bottom of page but It is getting hidden behind keyboard when keyboard visible after getting focus on same ion-input. Ionic page content is not getting scrolled up when keyboard visible. Kindly provide any solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you found any solution

Answer (score 0):

I am facing same issue in my app and I apply below solution to show my input on top of the screen.

Use overflow property to scroll your content to top.

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

Also if your app is in **fullscreen** mode you need to remove (**file : config.xml**) below line.

```
<preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
```

still facing any problem you can refer this ionic thread in this thread lots of tricks and tips mentioned to overcome this issue.

Thread Link : https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/scroll-to-the-focused-item-input-when-the-keyboard-is-up/422/15

Hope this will helps!

Answer (score 0):

Using Ionic-Native keyboard plugin, We can disable this setting.

```
this.keyboard.disableScroll(false);
```